# Loop through invoices from the bottom up untill transaction amount is reached

Tags: sql-server, loops

What I've thought up in my mind I can't find any helpful resources for online. I have a table that has a transaction amount per client. This amount is either zero or below zero. In another table I have invoices with total amounts per invoice per client. For all the transaction records that are below zero I want to calculate which invoices are still (partial) open.

Imagine client A has a transaction amount of -300 and client B has a transaction amount of -100. So there is a table with the fields client_id and transaction_amount. Then take a look at the Excel image below.

| client | invoice | amount | aggregated amount from last invoice up | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | invoice 101 | -25 | -575 | closed |
| A | invoice 102 | -100 | -550 | closed |
| A | invoice 103 | -100 | -450 | closed |
| A | invoice 104 | -75 | -350 | partial open |
| A | invoice 105 | -25 | -275 | fully open |
| A | invoice 106 | -150 | -250 | fully open |
| A | invoice 107 | -25 | -100 | fully open |
| A | invoice 108 | -75 | -75 | fully open |
| B | invoice 201 | -25 | -125 | closed |
| B | invoice 202 | -50 | -100 | fully open |
| B | invoice 203 | -25 | -50 | fully open |
| B | invoice 204 | -25 | -25 | fully open |

So when starting the calculation for client A at invoice 8 and working my way up by aggregating the amounts I see that invoices 5 through 8 are fully open and invoice 4 is partially open. For client B invoces 4 through 2 are open. I then want a query result that shows me those invoices for client A and B. Just so you know, the real dataset has lots of clients and lots of invoices.

In an extended version of what I would like to see you do not only see that invoice 4 is partially pasi, but you also see that an amount of 25 was paid, but 50 remains.

I think I need to have a reversed kind of loop? I've tried a few things by having an @transaction variable and subtracting the amounts, but it either keeps on running or returns the same invoice number over and over again. The result should be something like the image below.

| client | invoice | amount | amount open in transaction "debt amount" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | invoice 104 | -75 | -25 (-50 isn't in the transaction "debt amount": -75 + -25 + -150 + -25 + -25 = -300. That's why it's a partial in the status field.) |
| A | invoice 105 | -25 | -25 |
| A | invoice 106 | -150 | -150 |
| A | invoice 107 | -25 | -25 |
| A | invoice 108 | -75 | -75 |
| B | invoice 202 | -50 | -50 |
| B | invoice 203 | -25 | -25 |
| B | invoice 204 | -25 | -25 |

I can't imagine that I'm the first to want to do this, so if anyone has a link to documentation on how to do this or is able to help me in this topic, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also could you be more specific about how the "aggregated..." and "status" columns are derived? I don't quite follow the logic ....

Comment: `sum(amount) over (partition by client order by invoice desc)` will get you the aggregation value. As for the rest of it I can't quite make sense of what you want to see. You'll probably need a `lag()` to check for partially open.

Comment: @SOS thanks for your reaction and input, your absolutely right. I've changed the images to text. I'll try to make it more clear. Lets use client B. On the one side we have a transaction_amount of -100, that's like a debt. And on the other side we have four invoices, 204 being the last one. Now I want to know which of the four invoices are in the "debt amount", starting with the last one (204) and looping to the top one (201). Because the transaction_amount is -100 the invoices 204, 203, 202 are completly in the "debt amount". Invoice 201 isn't in the "debt amount". Does this make more sense?

Comment: (Updated) Thanks for the update. I think this should work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec9914bd8173102e0e051b5e948daa5f

Comment: Oh wait, shawnt00 was right about the sum(amount) over(...), no need for the unbounded when ordering the partition results by `invoice desc`. *Updated fiddle*: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc9405ab167bb55a53ae262747852e43

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much, this is exactly what I had in mind. It's beautiful in it's own simplicity. I'll go through it step by step and apply it to my real dataset. Again, thanks for the help. 

Comment: @SOS *no need for the unbounded* - indeed; default behavior of `sum()over(order by)` is ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

Comment: @CaiusJard - Yep, no idea what my sleep dep brain was thinking there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by SOS with some help from shawnt00. Thanks. See the dbfiddle result for the code.

> ```
> WITH cte AS (
>    SELECT client
>        , invoice
>        , amount
>        , status
>        , [debt amount]
>        , SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY invoice DESC) AS [aggregated amount from last invoice up]
>        , SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY invoice DESC) 
>           + ABS([debt amount]) AS RemainingDebt
>    FROM   YourTable
> )
> SELECT client
>        , invoice
>        , amount
>        , [aggregated amount from last invoice up]
>        , CASE WHEN RemainingDebt >= 0 THEN 'fully open'
>               WHEN ABS(RemainingDebt) < ABS(Amount) THEN 'partial open'
>               WHEN ABS(RemainingDebt) >= ABS(Amount) THEN 'closed' 
>          END AS status
> FROM   cte
> ORDER BY client, invoice
> ```

**Results:**

| client | invoice | amount | aggregated amount from last invoice up | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | invoice 101 | -25 | -575 | closed |
| A | invoice 102 | -100 | -550 | closed |
| A | invoice 103 | -100 | -450 | closed |
| A | invoice 104 | -75 | -350 | partial open |
| A | invoice 105 | -25 | -275 | fully open |
| A | invoice 106 | -150 | -250 | fully open |
| A | invoice 107 | -25 | -100 | fully open |
| A | invoice 108 | -75 | -75 | fully open |
| B | invoice 201 | -25 | -125 | closed |
| B | invoice 202 | -50 | -100 | fully open |
| B | invoice 203 | -25 | -50 | fully open |
| B | invoice 204 | -25 | -25 | fully open |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc9405ab167bb55a53ae262747852e43)*

Comment: You might want to add the code inside the answer instead of just linking to a fiddle. Fiddles are good, but in general, responses should always hold all necessary information without the use of external sites. They're a good visual extra, but that is about it.